# How to do "If cell contains" in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code to do an statement when a cell contain the number "1".

I have been using this code found online.

```
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "1") Then
MsgBox ("Yes")
Else
MsgBox ("no")
End If
```

However this work if it only read cell C6. How do i set it in such a way that it will read a range of cell from C2:C5000. Like my cell D2 will show "yes" when cell C2 show "1" and cell D3 show "No" when Cell C3 show a different number?.

Thanks for the big help

Horo

Comment: Use a loop.  The code you provided only specifies one cell.  You probably want to loop through a range of cells instead.  You might also consider a relative formula containing a conditional instead of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can avoid loops this way:

```
Columns(3).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=1,""yes"",""no"")"
```

and if you want to get rid of formulas:

```
With Columns(3).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=1,""yes"",""no"")"
    .value = .value
End With
```

Comment: i tried to intergrate your formula intomy vba, it does not work, i am not too sure why.

Comment: i tried to intergrate your formula into my vba, it does not work, i am not too sure why.  My code is as follow.                                                               With Columns(3).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=1 Then"
                    rng = mRng
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rng.Row & ":N" & rng.Row).Interior.Color = 5287936.                                                                                                        I tried to improvise it by highlighting it green but cannot work. what is wrong?

Comment: You have to type it in your VBA just as I wrote it. Let me know

Comment: Hi, I want it in it in such a way that if column C has 1, the corresponding row from column N will be highlighted. instead of having yes no. Hope is not confusing for you. and thanks for all the help

Comment: Well that's quite a different thing than what you asked in your post, and you'll need "classic" loop for that. BTW if I solved your _original_ question (_"like my cell D2 will show "yes" when cell C2 show "1" and cell D3 show "No" when Cell C3 show a different number"_) then please mark answer as accepted. Thank you!